# Copy PDF to Paint.net black text turns blue

Tags: pdf, resolution, colors, copy-paste, paint.net

I used the snipping tool to copy a table from a PDF and pasted it into paint.net.

On zooming in the border is a solid black line and the numbers/text are multicolored blue/brown/yellow so it looks black (but fuzzy) when you zoom out and you see the colors when zoomed all the way in.  Does this have to do with layers from the PDF, or the way text is handled, it is baffling to me that the line and text from the same snip have such a contrast in clarity.

(I checked and the original PDF is solid black)

Is snipping tool converting the colors or is it paint.net, or something else? What would be the next step in figuring out what's causing it?
(The hoped for solution would provide less "fuzzy" numbers after pasting.)

[This is a comparison of zooming in vs not, the border remains clear but the text gets a border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pIik.png)

[This is post snip, pre-paste, it appears .net changes the colors for the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vnJj.png)

Comment: Is it possible to show us a bit of the image? Like a screenshot of what you see in paint.net?

Comment: @LPChip I realized that would be helpful and edited the comment.

Comment: Hmm I have no idea what causes this actually.

Comment: I had a surprise with the paint bucket using anti-aliasing to smooth the border similar to what it did to the text which leads me to wonder if it is performing anti-aliasing on the pasted image.

Answer (score 0):

This link was helpful in explaining anti-aliasing and how it affects the way a program displays images and pixels. The PDF doesn't display an image per-say but is displaying vector based text. When the text gets converted to an image paint.net has to figure out how to split the pixels and it does that with anti-aliasing. That is why the border which doesn't split pixels looks fine and the numbers and text get anti-aliased.

http://www.howtogeek.com/73704/what-is-anti-aliasing-and-how-does-it-affect-my-photos-and-images/

If you want text to look good small, it's probably best to use a text editor or some program that can handle vector text like word, illustrator, etc.

Comment: This doesn't answer: why doesn't the save from the snipping tool get visibly anti-aliased?